# Smarty foreach arbitrary loop - use index to add different classes?

Tags: foreach, indexing, smarty

I have an array called $items, and i'm trying to style only the first 3 items different from the rest. I thought the following code...

```
{foreach from=$items item=item}
  {if $smarty.foreach.item.index < 3}
    <div class="style1">{$item->title}</div>
  {elseif $smarty.foreach.item.index >= 3}
    <div class="style2">{$item->title}</div>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

...would result in this markup...

```
<div class="style1">item title value</div>
<div class="style1">item title value</div>
<div class="style1">item title value</div>

<div class="style2">item title value</div>
<div class="style2">item title value</div>
<div class="style2">item title value</div>
<div class="style2">item title value</div>
<div class="style2">item title value</div>
...
```

...but it doesn't. Any suggestions or better options?

Comment: Using a {counter} did the job but i'd still like to know what i did wrong with the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give your foreach loop a name, that way you can reference the iteration number.

```
{foreach from=$items item=item name=itemList}
  {if $smarty.foreach.itemList.iteration < 3}
    <div class="style1">{$item->title}</div>
  {elseif $smarty.foreach.itemList.iteration >= 3}
    <div class="style2">{$item->title}</div>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining Adrian, that's exactly what i tried to achieve! No need for a {counter} this way. I'll dive into the index myself to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Yeh it's a handy way. Because then you can use, `.itemList.last` & `itemList.first` etc.